# stackmob error on callback

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, stackmob

I am using stackmob for few days and it is still new and there is no much information on the web. I have encountered this issue: I won't to get list of all the store name I have in my stackmobe "db" the scheme called store and here is the code I am using:

```
var Store = StackMob.Model.extend({
    schemaName: 'store'
});

 var stores = new Store();
stores.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
        //after we've gotten all the Todo items from StackMob, let's see what we have!
        console.debug(collection.toJSON());
        alert(collection.toJSON());
    },
    error: function(collection, response){
        alert(collection.toJSON());
    }
});
```

I am getting this errors in my chrome log:

```
OPTIONS http://api.stackmob.com/store 400 (Bad Request) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.stackmob.com/store. Origin http://127.0.0.1:4567 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling the API? Looks like you just need to use `JSONP` and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Where to use it, can you provide some code?

Comment: What do you mean by how do you call the API?

Comment: I meant, how are you requesting the data from stackmob? Can you post your `collection`?

Comment: the collection called `store`, and it has many fields. does it meters which fields does it has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I ask what environment you're running in (chrome, firefix, safari, opera, phonegap)? By default, the JS SDK is configured to make AJAX calls to a relative path. e.g. "/store"  It looks like somehow it's configured to hit "api.stackmob.com" directly, which only happens in these cases:

- the JS SDK detects that you're using PhoneGap
- you've specified the URL to hit api.stackmob.com directly via the init:

  StackMob.init({
    ...
    apiURL: 'http://api.stackmob.com/'
  })

The first question I ask myself is how it's making a call to api.stackmob.com while it looks like you're running on the Python server:  (I assume that's what it is because I'm seeing 127.0.0.1:4567 in your original post)

Another thing that Dennis Rongo pointed out above is your Python version.  We tested with 2.7 but it sounds like he's noting an issue with 3.3.  But it's still unexpected that you're hitting api.stackmob.com from 127.0.0.1:4567.  Do you have apiURL: '...' set in your init?  If so, I would try removing that.

Setting apiURL will make the SDK call api.stackmob.com directly (api.stackmob.com/store), and the browser will behave like it would for any regular AJAX call and block it if it's going cross domain, giving the error you see.

Well, let me know!  We definitely want to get you going!

Erick

PS I think you're also trying to get more than one store.  StackMob.Model only represents one store.  You want StackMob.Collection.

e.g.

```
var Store = StackMob.Model.extend({ schemaName: 'store' });
var Stores = StackMob.Collection.extend({ model: Store });

var stores = new Stores();
stores.fetch({
  success: function(results) {
    console.log(results.toJSON()); //should print out array of JSON objects representing your store items.
  }
});
```

More info:
http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/js/Query-an-Object

Comment: Hi Erick, I am using cordova for my app and I figured out that when I delete the include of the cordova js file every thing works fine. It is not the real solution of course

Comment: I see!  Yes, what is happening is that when you include cordova.js, the JS SDK detects that you're in PhoneGap mode, and it sets itself to point to api.stackmob.com.  My guess is that you were running in both PhoneGap and the Python Web Server in order to develop locally.  In PhoneGap it would work fine.  In the Python Web Server, cordova.js would kick it into a mode that would hit api.stackmob.com, which wouldn't work in the Python Web Server because browsers have cross domain restrictions.  PhoneGap does not.    Many thanks and Kudos to Dennis Rongo for contributing his time to help out.

Comment: Thanks for using us!  If you have any follow up questions, don't hesitate to find us at https://support.stackmob.com.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used StackMob before but decided to check it out and was able to make it work locally (`localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1/`).

There's a few things that you can look at.

- Go to your `StackMob Dashboard` and check your `Schema` on whether your permission level is set correctly. If any of your Actions are not set to `Open`, check whether you're properly authenticating first prior to making the `Fetch()` call.
- You also need to install Python 2.7+ (I recommend sticking to 2.7 as 3.3 will break their `Python` script). [Installation instructions](https://dashboard.stackmob.com/sdks/js/config). Python can be downloaded [here](http://www.python.org/getit/).

  The installation instruction includes `stackmobserver.py` which you need to put on your project's root directory. Navigate to your project's root and execute the `Python` script using the `Command` to initialize (for development purposes only).

  > python stackmobserver.py
- Check your `init` and `authentication` script.

  ```
  /** Initialize StackMob */
  StackMob.init({...});

  /** Perform authentication using User schema */
  var user = new StackMob.User({ username: 'yourUser', password: 'yourPassword' });
  user.login(false, {
      success: function (model) {
      /** Perform the Model fetch for the authenticated user. */
      },
      error: function (model, response) {
          console.debug(response);
      }
  });
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: every thing reconfigured well, this happens in every browser but in my android emulator I am getting the callback and there is no error

Comment: Are you using the latest JS file posted on their site?

Comment: yes, it is probably something with the python file they provide, i think it is not configured right. I am opening the python file and then opening my html file from the relative path of the python file; like this: 7.0.0.1:4567/assets/www/index.html

Comment: So the `Python` proxy is not running or throwing an exception at all? Are you seeing all the request coming through the `Console` app? Is the `Python` file within the same directory as `index.html`?

Comment: no, but as you can see the path is relative to the file and the index file. and the the logs of the python cmd are changing I am getting a lot of "404 file not found": ` 3dns-2.adobe.com - - [13/Feb/2013 19:51:13] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
3dns-2.adobe.com - - [13/Feb/2013 19:51:13] code 404, message File not found
3dns-2.adobe.com - - [13/Feb/2013 19:51:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Can you try moving the `Python` file to the root of your web app and run the script again? Or have you tried that already?

Comment: What server-side framework are you using? Does your app contain a `crossdomain.xml` file? Just throwing it in there since I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: there is some conflict with the cordova.js file. whene i remove it, every thing works. now it is a new problem.

Comment: Dennis thanks for trying out StackMob in order to give Vlad a hand.  It's very thoughtful of you, and we at StackMob appreciate your curiosity!

Comment: @ErickTai: I find that StackMob is easy to use once everything has been configured correctly. Researching this question helps me understand it further and wouldn't be able to know more about it if not for the question. I'll be using it a lot more on future projects definitely. ;)